# What firewalls can I buy that will site to site VPN with a Sonicwall TZ 190

Tags: sonicwall, site-to-site-vpn

I need to buy something to site to site VPN with a TZ 190.

Sorry, I'm not much of a network expert. I'm a programmer.

Could someone give me some suggestions regarding which makes and models can site to site VPN with the TZ 190. Will the TZ 100 work?

Please don't tell me what should work, tell me what you've SEEN work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TZ 210 is successor of TZ 190 so it has to work just by definition. The VPN protocol it uses is IPSEC, so pretty much any standard IPSEC client should work. I tried it in the past with OpenSwan and FreeBSD and they both worked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the TZ 210 will work. Anything that supports standard IPSEC tunnels should be sufficient.

[Sonicwall TZ Series Product Comparison Chart](http://www.sonicwall.com.tw/us/products/13281.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've setup VPN tunnel between a Zywall USG 20 and Sonicwall NSA 240. Not exactly apples to apples, it's pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

I have good experience with Fortigate 50, 60 and 100 against Sonicwall 170 (close enough?).

Works perfectly. They both are good VPN firewalls and follow the IPSEC standard close enough to setup VPN between them.

Comment: well that's what i was worried about, does the sonicwall follow the standard? I was pretty worried because third party vpn clients weren't connecting to it too well

Answer (score 0):

I believe astaro security gateway solutions will work but to be sure you could download the home edition to test first.